# sample() with list

Tags: r

Is is possible to sample a single column at random from a list that looks similar to below.

```
list(combinations(4,3,1:4),combinations(4,2,1:4))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    4
[3,]    1    3    4
[4,]    2    3    4

[[2]]
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

I was trying to combine the columns into a list of 1d matrices eg. list(matrix[,1],matrix[,2]...), but was having trouble getting that working as well.  Since the matrices have different dimensions I wasn't really sure how to go about this.

Comment: From your comment below, it's less clear what you really want.  Your sample has five columns of data in two separate matrices.  It's trivially easy to combine any of them with `foo <- c(mat[[1]][,2],mat[[2]][,1]`  . What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: (Echoing Carl) do you want exactly one of the 5 columns shown - of height either 4 (for the first 3) or 6 (for the last 2)?

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't write the question well.  Yes I want a single column in total, not a single column from each matrix.

Comment: I could tell you how to do that, too, but now I'm nervous you're going to change the question _completely_, _again_.

Comment: Sorry joran.  I didn't think I was being that vague.  Maybe I should edit the question to show the desired form of the output I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, and be sure to change the title back to reflect what you mean as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't find the meaning of the original question confusing. It has a title that is totally wrong, but joran is the one who added the title.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman It was "sample a single column at random" that sent me down the wrong path. I was waiting for the OP to edit it all back, but I'll roll it back in the meantime.

Comment: I totally see why you read the question that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it that starts by flattening the matrices into a list of columns:

```
> library(gtools)
> matrices <- list(combinations(4,3,1:4),combinations(4,2,1:4))
> columns <- do.call(c, lapply(matrices, function(x) as.list(as.data.frame(x))))
> columns
$V1
[1] 1 1 1 2

$V2
[1] 2 2 3 3

$V3
[1] 3 4 4 4

$V1
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3

$V2
[1] 2 3 4 3 4 4

> columns[[sample(length(columns), 1)]]
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
> columns[[sample(length(columns), 1)]]
[1] 2 3 4 3 4 4
> columns[[sample(length(columns), 1)]]
[1] 2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple application of `lapply`, `as.vector` and `do.call`:

```
l <- list(matrix(1:16,4,4),matrix(1:8,4,2),matrix(1:20,4,5))                        
rs <-lapply(l,as.vector)
matrix(do.call(c,rs),ncol = 1)
```

But that's my last attempt. If you change the question again, I'm just deleting this and moving on. ;)

Comment: The only thing is that i want a single column (in total) even though there are two sublists.

Comment: @matt_k Hopefully that helps.